# Jenkins - Steps after build

Tags: .net, jenkins, sql-server-data-tools

I am new to Jenkins. I managed to build my .Net solution and SQL (SSDT) solution using Jenkins. It produces a bin folder (with required dlls, exes and dacpac files).

I would like to store my build with a version number and deploy the version to selected app server.

How can I achieve this? Is there a good article explaining how to do this?

Comment: I'm using [Artifact Deployer Plugin](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ArtifactDeployer+Plugin) to store build artifacts. For Windows SAMBA share target path wil be somethig like `\\server_name\share\project_name\${JOB_NAME}-build_${BUILD_NUMBER}`. Jenkins will automatically replace variables with job name and build number. Deploying depends on your exact deployment process, is it done by ftp, or webdeploy?

Comment: where do you want to store version number?

Comment: @run -thanks for your input. Currently we are manually deploying by copying for a bin folder. What is the recommended process to deploy .Net websites, services? Thanks.

Comment: @Dmitrij Kultasev - I can store version number inside a text file within repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should store the result in a binary repository like Sonatype Nexus.
On their website they show how you can use Nexus for your articats lifecycle managment.

Comment: Thanks @Holleoman. It looks like I will be using Nexus. I tried searching online on "how to upload .Net artifacts using Nexus". I havent found a good article so far. Some of them suggesting to use maven  - do I need to?

Comment: I your the official Jenkins plugin from Sonatype. You establish the connection in the plugin setting. and then you have a simple one line pipeline step to upload your artifact to a maven repository. Works like a charm.

Comment: Just use the offical documentation https://help.sonatype.com/integrations/nexus-and-continuous-integration/nexus-platform-plugin-for-jenkins#NexusPlatformPluginforJenkins-PipelineStep -> scroll to Publish / Deploy Components. There is your pipeline code